# Javascript Querying on Elasticsearch does not work on Child Elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, children, querying

I am trying to display searchresults on a elasticsearch database in my reactjs-app. Nevertheless I can only access the upper layer of key value pairs and am unable to reach the children.

The structure of my elasticsearch-objects is as follows:

```
...
"hits":[{
"_index":"knowledgecrawler",
"_type":"doc",
"_id":"5fea73f38399f4c01f",
"_score":1.0,
"_source":{
        "content":"content comes here",
        "meta":{
                "author":"Jones@stackoverflow.com",
                "title":"I am lost"
                "date":"today",
                "keywords":["Stackoverflow"],
                "language":"Javascript",
                }
        "raw":{
                "date":"2017-03-08",
                "subject":"How do I get here?"
                }
        }}]
```

The elasticsearch-object is much bigger, but I am only searching in the "hits". With the following lines of code i can easily display the firstlevel values(_index, _type, _id), but any attempt to access the children failed so far:

```
render() {
    const result = this.props.result;
        return (
            <div className={this.props.bemBlocks.item().mix(this.props.bemBlocks.container("item"))} key={result._id}>
                <div className={this.props.bemBlocks.item("title")}>{result._id}</div>
                <div className={this.props.bemBlocks.item("title")}>{result._type}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Can anybody advice me how to access the children of `_source`. E.g. I want to display the author in my frontend.

**EDIT:**

So the error is apparently due to the fact that the `_source` field in Elasticsearch is not indexed and thus not searchable (according to the [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html)). 
 I haven't come up with a solution so far, but will post it here, when I find it. Help is also much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have following data:

```
data = {"hits":[{
"_index":"knowledgecrawler",
"_type":"doc",
"_id":"5fea73f38399f4c01f",
"_score":1.0,
"_source":{
        "content":"content comes here",
        "meta":{
                "author":"Jones@stackoverflow.com",
                "title":"I am lost"
                "date":"today",
                "keywords":["Stackoverflow"],
                "language":"Javascript",
                }
        "raw":{
                "date":"2017-03-08",
                "subject":"How do I get here?"
                }
        }}]}
```

Now you question is : **Can anybody advice me how to access the children of _source. E.g. I want to display the author in my frontend.**

So, you can do the following to get the `author` of `_source`:

```
{data.hits && data.hits.length > 0 && data.hits[0]._source && data.hits[0]._source.meta && data.hits[0]._source.meta.author ?data.hits[0]._source.meta.author : ''}
```

If you have multiple hits, then you can use [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```
data.hits.map(value => value._source && value._source.meta && value._source.meta.author ? value._source.meta.author : '')
```

Comment: No errors. But my frontend does not display the values (This works when I stay on the top level)

Comment: Ok sorry. It throws the following error: TypeError: "result._source.meta is undefined" where result is the data.hits object.

Comment: Then you need to check if `result._source.meta` is not undefined and then print it.

Comment: It got rid of the error. But the author is still not displayed. But thank you anyways for your efforts. I very much appreciate it!